# Can Android studio run on Google Pixel C

Tags: android, android-studio

I always hope that Google will build a tablet for developers. I know there is a way to get Google Pixel 2 to run android studio. How about Pixel C?

Comment: pixel c runs on android OS. I doubt it will be possible.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think so because the system requirement not specify that

https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm right but Pixel C is basically a Chromebook no? Then you should be able to do it following this guide:

http://tamingandroidcode.blogspot.be/2013/12/running-android-studio-on-chromebook.html

You'll have to use Crouton to install a Linux distribution of your choosing. Then you should be able to run Android Studio.